# Passing Parameter(s) To A Subquery

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a SQL query

```
SELECT targetDate, anEvent
FROM myTable mt
JOIN lookupTable lookup 
  ON lookup.startDate < mt.targetDate AND endDate > mt.targetDate
```

When I try to make it into a subquery

```
SELECT targetDate, sub.anEvent
FROM myTable mt
JOIN
(
  SELECT anEvent
  FROM lookupTable lookup
  WHERE lookup.startDate < mt.targetDate AND endDate > mt.targetDate
) sub
```

I get the error message "mt is not defined".
I need to make it a subquery, how can I correct it?

Comment: seems an alias `mt` for `myTable` missing in the below query

Comment: It is meant to be that way, trying to see if there is some way of bridging the scope of the alias. Editted.

Comment: It seems that your reference to table `mt` in the subquery is trying to make it a correlated subquery. I don’t believe this can be done in a derived table, correlation typically is placed in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 2):

Why doing a subselect?  You first query was perfect.

```
SELECT targetDate, anEvent
FROM myTable mt
JOIN lookupTable lookup 
ON lookup.startDate < mt.targetDate AND endDate > mt.targetDate
```

Comment: We're trying to stick to a coding standard.

Comment: Subselect is not always a good idea.  Which coding standard you want to stick to?

Comment: I understand it may not be as performant, but we're trying to keep things logically grouped so easier to read by those not as used to looking at SQL. This is only part of a much larger query.

Comment: Coding standards should enforce good programming practices and efficiency. If you want your code to be easier to read, consider formatting and comment blocks if this is part of a script.

Answer (score 0):

Same result you can achieve by following this.

```
SELECT T.targetDate, T.anEvent

FROM 
(
  SELECT targetDate, anEvent
FROM myTable mt
JOIN lookupTable lookup 
  ON lookup.startDate < mt.targetDate AND endDate > mt.targetDate
) T
```

hope this will work.